# Object released without my consent

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm currently rewriting an app, and i can't explain myself this bug :

I've a class "Player" with an NSMutableArray named "pieces".
When I remove from this array the last "Piece" object of my first player (i've got two and this bug occurs only with the first one), the Player object is dealloc'd.

If you have any idea for this bug... 
I'm still here if you need any piece of code to understand...

Comment: You probably (auto)released that object somewhere else. Please show code where you put data into the array, and where you delete it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just have run another tests and my problem is not with the array...

When my array is empty (only in this case), when I call this line :
piece.owner = player;
my old player is dealloc'd

Comment: You are not retaining the player enough.  Show us the code where you create the player object and assign it to an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because owner property is probably implemented as retain property.

So pieces own a reference to player and player is not dealloc until your last piece is released.  You probably release your player where you shouldn't and retain it where you shouldn't as well (in piece object).

Replace the owner property with (nonatomic, assign) and track the place where you release the player.

Comment: OK my player was retained at two places, but it was the source of the bug, as a beginner in this language, I over-used the retain property. I've now understood how to use it. Thank you !

Comment: You really, really need to read the IOS memory management article that you will found on the Apple Dev Site. It will take you 30 min to read and will avoid you hours of debugging and wondering what you are missing.